# JS Using variables name instead of their value in a function

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a problem when trying to give an array (or variable) a new value. Inside a function, I want to give a new value to a variable pointed out by the parameters when executing the function.

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;

function editvariable (target, newValue) {
    var target = newValue;
}

editvariable(a, 4);
```

In this example, I want to change the value of `a` to 4, but it will only make a new function called target.

Comment: How about `a = 4`? I feel like you probably have a broader goal you are trying to accomplish, but without more details it's hard to tell.

Comment: Primitive variables are not passed by reference, but by value only, meaning you can't pass the variable like that and change the original etc.

Comment: You could also just return the value and assign it back to the variable. So `a = editvariable(a,4)` and inside `editvariable` you need to `return target` (or `newValue` since it's the same). Of course, this is still nothing more than simple assignment but I assume you have a (real) function that does more than simply assign a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is defined out of the function scope, so you can simply set `a = newValue`

But why would you want to make a function for what a simple assignment statement can do?

If you *really* want to have `target` re-assign `a`, you'll have to return the result.

```
var a=0;
var b=0;

function editvariable(target,newValue){
    target=newValue;
    return target; //return the assignment
}

a = editvariable(a,4)
```

Comment: I'm going to guess they probably want to also be able to do `editvariable(b,4)`

Comment: Most likely, but it's overhead. Either way, assigning the variable inside the function will still work, but the parameter is not a reference of the original variable. He'll have to return it and assign `a` to it

Answer (score 0):

```
var target=newValue;
```

Just remove `var`.

Comment: Good thought, but I'm not certain that would do what the OP wants because of passing by value.